# Web notification based on pubnub

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I am using pubnub for web based notification on my project. I integrated pubnub and using pubnub subscribe method to show new message available on my channel. But once the page refreshed i can't able to identify new message available in my channel or not. Any other method available in pubnub any new message available in channel in page refresh also.

Please suggest one method for this issue. Now i am showing web based push notification only based on Pubnub subscribe.

Example Code:

```
$scope.showNotification = function (newmessage){
  var ms = 30000; // close notification after 30sec
  if ((typeof Notification === 'function') && (typeof Notification != 'undefined')) {
    var notification = new Notification('name' , {
      body: newmessage.message.fromName+" : "+newmessage.message.topic,
      icon: 'images/logo.png'
    });
  }
  notification.onshow = function() {
    setTimeout(notification.close, ms);
  };
  notification.onclick = function(){$rootScope.announceClick(newmessage.message.type,newmessage)};
}

  Pubnub.subscribe({
    channel: $scope.userID,
    callback: function (newMsg) {
      var newmessage = {};
      newmessage.message = newMsg;
      $scope.showNotification(newmessage);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: @CraigConover i added my example code in my question. can you please check.

Comment: Does your page refresh trigger the Pubnub to be initialized? If not, make it so.